# XEN package installing through yocto

Tags: xen, hypervisor

I am trying to add `xen` package to `imx8mp` through `yocto`.

1. in `conf/local.conf`, I have added this line `DISTRO_FEATURES:append = " xen"`, but no package is coming in image what should iI do?
2. Also, I have tried with `DISTRO_FEATURES_append = " xen"`,  but no use?
   3.if I add this line `IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " xen"`, package is coming in rootfs file but no use as
   I am neither getting error package related to it.

I get this error as package not installed:

```
 u-boot=> run xenmmcboot
## Error: "xenmmcboot" not defined
```

Can any one help?

I tried to add through `local.conf` as already recipe for them are present.